# form elements fade out with jQuery on selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JavaScript code to fade out elements when a certain option is selected in the form, here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function opt_onchange() {
        if (document.getElementById("opt").value == "banscan") {
            document.getElementById("form_username").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("form_password").style.visibility = "hidden";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("form_username").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("form_password").style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        if (document.getElementById("opt").value == "") {
            document.getElementById("submit").style.visibility = "hidden";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("submit").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
</script>
```

When the option banscan is selected, the top 2 fields username and password fade out. But in Javascript they fade out instantly.

As I'm using bootstrap 3 on the website I thought I should try out jQuery as it is already available. I've read through some jQuery tutorials but I can't find anything specific to what I need. Here is my attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function opt_onchange() {

        if (document.getElementById("opt").value == "") {
            document.getElementById("submit").style.visibility = "hidden";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("submit").style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        if (document.getElementById("opt").value == "banscan") {
            $("form_username").fadeOut();
            $("form_password").fadeOut();
        } else {
            $("form_username").fadeIn();
            $("form_password").fadeIn();
        }
    }
</script>
```

However, this code doesn't work at all.

Edit:

Here is my updated code, now I just need to make the submit button fade out on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#submit").fadeOut();
            });

            function opt_onchange() {
                if (document.getElementById("opt").value == "") {
                    $("#submit").fadeOut();
                } else {
                    $("#submit").fadeIn();
                }

                if (document.getElementById("opt").value == "banscan") {
                    $("#form_username").fadeOut();
                    $("#form_password").fadeOut();
                } else {
                    $("#form_username").fadeIn();
                    $("#form_password").fadeIn();
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: You forgot the `#` in the selectors, e.g. `$('#form_username')`

Comment: Ah, yes I added them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user3237539 pointed out, your jQuery selectors must begin with '#'.  Your code should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function opt_onchange() {

    if (document.getElementById("opt").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("submit").style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("submit").style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    if (document.getElementById("opt").value == "banscan") {
        $("#form_username").fadeOut();
        $("#form_password").fadeOut();
    } else {
        $("#form_username").fadeIn();
        $("#form_password").fadeIn();
    }
}
</script>
```

Hope that helps!

PS: Whenever you use `document.getElementById()` you could instead use `$("#id")` to be able to use more of jQuery's helpful functions.  You could replace `document.getElementById("submit").style.visibility = "hidden";`
with `$("#submit).hide();`